# How can I create this specific d3.js graph in Angular TypeScript project?

Tags: angular, typescript, d3.js, graph

I want to make this specific chart in angular project. Can any one help how can I? Because I am facing many errors.

FYI: source of data for me is local object not CSV file example:

```
const data = [
        { time: 0, misalignment: -4.5891478772}, { time: 1, misalignment: -4.8211986847}, 
        { time: 3, misalignment: -4.8211986847 }, { time: 4, misalignment: -4.4910716658}
        ];
```

[link of connected scattered chart](https://observablehq.com/@d3/connected-scatterplot/2?intent=fork)
Kindly checkout the link. Animation shown there is quite Important.

```
const data = [
        { time: 0, misalignment: -4.5891478772}, { time: 1, misalignment: -4.8211986847}, 
        { time: 3, misalignment: -4.8211986847 }, { time: 4, misalignment: -4.4910716658}
        ];
        
        const xExtent = d3.extent(data, d => d.time);
        if (xExtent[0] === undefined || xExtent[1] === undefined) {
          throw new Error('Invalid data');
        }
        const x = d3.scaleLinear()
                    .domain(xExtent).nice()
                    .range([this.marginLeft, this.width - this.marginRight]);
        
        const yExtent = d3.extent(data, d => d.misalignment);
        if (yExtent[0] === undefined || yExtent[1] === undefined) {
          throw new Error('Invalid data');
        }
        
        const y = d3.scaleLinear()
                  .domain(yExtent).nice()
                  .range([this.height - this.marginBottom, this.marginTop]),

      
        const line = d3.line()
          .curve(d3.curveCatmullRom)
          .x(d => x(d.time))
          .y(d => y(d.misalignment));

        const svg = d3.create("svg")
          .attr("width", this.width)
          .attr("height", this.height)
          .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, this.width, this.height])
          .attr("style", "max-width: 100%; height: auto;");
```

> this is the code I have written, and the error I am getting is:
> 1.Property 'time' does not exist on type '[number, number]'.ts(2339)
> 2.Property 'misalignment' does not exist on type '[number, number]'.ts(2339)

can anyone guide me how can I achieve this graph with animation using local data source? Not CSV file. file.